# Python Nested List Space Complexity

Tags: python, space-complexity

For example, what would the space complexity be for such list? `[[1,2,3,...,n]]`
How does python store the list inside another list?

Comment: Probably it has it row by row... e.g. [[1,2,3,...,n]] will be stored similar way as [1,2,3,...,n].
If you have [ [1,2,3,...,n], [1,2,3,...,n] ] that will be stored as 2 rows with n columns